# Modify data inside thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing unit tests for one of the classes I want to test. Function `infFooLoop()` what I want to test is executed in endless loop (request to stop it comes externally). My problem is I want to change the private variable `state_` via setter in `setState` when function executes in separate thread asynchronously. Some simplified code example is here:

```
enum class State : int
{
    Success = 1,
    Failure = 2
};

class Foo
{
private:
    State state_{State::Success};
    bool stop_flag_{false};

public:
    void setState(State state) { state_ = state; }
    void infFooLoop(bool &start)
    {
        while (start)
        {
            std::cout << "While loop executes \n";
            if (state_ == State::Failure)
            {
                stop_flag_ = true;
            }
            else if (stop_flag_)
            {
                std::cout << "Program stopped\n";
                // Report error but for this example break
                break;
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    Foo obj;
    bool flag{true};

    std::future<void> future = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){ obj.infFooLoop(flag);});
    
    // Try to change the data:
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    // I want to change data for `Failure` so stop_flag condition will be used
    obj.setState(State::Failure);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    // terminate loop
    flag = false;

    return 0;
}
```

`state_` will be taken from external component and `stop_flag_` is used to handle some corner-case here (in real it wont break the loop, just report error to different component).

I assume `infFooLoop` executes on a separate thread so I can't just call another function in a different thread to change this data. `stop_flag_` is some internal variable used only in this one function so I want to leave it as simple as possible (do not introduce mutexes/atomic in `Foo` class only for tests). Can you give me some suggestions on what should I do here?

Comment: *"do not introduce mutexes/atomic in Foo class only for tests"* Synchronizing variables accessed by multiple threads is not optional.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are asking exactly. It seems like you described a goal, but haven't specified any problem or obstacle you need help with.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly? Your production code has no threads at all (i.e. everything executes in the main thread), but because there is an infinite loop, you want to use threads in testing to be able to send the stop signal into the infinite loop?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: My problem is that I want to have control over 'state_' private variable when 'infFooLoop' is executed in thread. I am trying to call this method 'obj.setState(State::Failure)' what does not change data for me. My problem is how it can be changed during 'infFooLoop' execution (for example function executes for 5s and after 2s I want to trigger change of 'state_' variable)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Not really.  I do not care about condition for this infinite loop at all. In real application I take it by reference form another module what has control over my app. Here is only simplified example.What I want to do is just start this loop in separate thread for testing purposes and during execution modify some internal data (variable 'state_')

Comment: From my understanding 'obj.setState' will be executed in separate thread, different than asynchronous 'infFooLoop'. For this reason I have to somehow exchange data between these two threads but no idea how to do it (status_ should be atomic? But then, what's next...). Or can I call obj.SetState on the same thread as infFooLoop, but then how?

Comment: You can call functions and change data from a different thread just fine. All threads run in the same process, so they share the memory. But since there will be two threads accessing the same variable, you are required to provide synchronisation, otherwise your program will have Undefined Behaviour. The reason I'm trying to clarify your situation is that what you want (running loop in one thread and controlling it from another) is not possible without making your code thread-aware and using some sort of synchronisation (the easiest being simply `std::atomic<State> state_`)

Comment: Yeah, simple as that and working. Thanks @Yksisarvinen, idk why I missed it. Solved.

Comment: @Daniel I'm curious about what CPU architecture and compiler you were using that experienced this issue?

Comment: It's ARM architecture but I cannot tell more unfortunately.